# Add autocomplete feature to rails app with selectize.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, autocomplete, selectize.js

It's been two days that I'm fighting on a "simple" task. Adding an autocomplete field in a form on my rails application.

I'm running ruby 2.3.3 and rails 5.0.1. So far I've tried a bunch of different options such as:
- Elasticsearch
- Rails-jquery-autocomplete

Now I'm giving a go to selectize.js. I added the gem to my gemfile:

```
gem "selectize-rails"
```

And I have included it in my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require selectize
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
//= require main
```

I have created an action in my controller that returns the data from a table called Interests in a json format:

```
def users_interests_search
    @interests = Interest.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
        format.json {render json: @interests}
    end
end
```

And in my script, I'm using the following (taken from [here](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) using the rottenTomato example):

```
$('.test-selectize').selectize({
    valueField: 'title',
    labelField: 'title',
    searchField: 'title',
    options: [],
    create: false,
    render: {
        option: function(item, escape) {
          return '<div>' +
                      '<span class="title">' +
                          '<span class="ciccioname">' + item.name + '</span>' +
                      '</span>' +
                  '</div>';
        }
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/users-interests-search',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res[0].name)
                $('selectize-dropdown-content').append('<span class="ciccioname">' + res[0].name + '</span>')
            }
        });
    }
  });
```

Although I do see the AJAX call made and the JSON returned, not much is going on on the actual page.

Any suggestion on the matter is the very welcome (or any other sort of help to get an autocomplete system up and running for that matter :) ).

Cheers!
Andrea

Update: Here is the console output after changing the ajax call (see above)

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7yMQ.png)

Comment: What do you see in the browser's console? I'm guessing some kind of error? Your backend seems to send an array of interests, but you only call `res.name`, without iterating them.

Comment: Hey @Wukerplank - yes indeed I should iterate the array, however I still get the same behaviour by using res[0].name (which when logged in the console shows the data I'm looking for).

Comment: Can you add the result you receive in the browser? Maybe its root is a dictionary and you need to call `res['interests'][0].name`

Comment: Sure, you have it!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I opted for an easier solution.

This is my controller:

```
def users_interests_search
    term = params[:term] || nil
    @interests = Interest.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%") if term

    @names = []

    @interests.each do |i|
        @names.push(i.name)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
        format.json {render json: @names}
    end
end
```

And this is my view (using the tagsInput jQuery plugin):

```
$('.ajax-autocomplete').tagsInput({
    autocomplete_url: "/users-interests-search?term=" + $('.ajax-autocomplete').val()
  });
```